# Automatically "link keyboard and mouse" to iPad with Universal Control?

Tags: universal-control

Universal Control can "Link keyboard and mouse" to an iPad, which just controls the iPad with the keyboard and mouse that are already assigned to your Apple computer.

This is different than "Mirror or extend to", which merely uses the iPad as a another dumb display.

However, Universal Control often disconnects from the iPad when the computer or iPad go to sleep, and it seems to be random.

**How can Universal Control keep the mouse and keyboard linked to the iPad persistently?**

## Universal Control in System Settings

`System Settings > Displays > Link keyboard and mouse to`

[image]

Comment: If there was a keyboard shortcut or script which could be used as an alternative to going through the UI to re-enable UC that would also be helpful.